# View logs before last hard shut down

Tags: freeze

I can not remember how to view the logs for the moments before the last hard shutdown. I remember it had a "-1" where you can change the number to go back to previous events. I used it last time my computer froze, but I can not find the thread I learned it from. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo journalctl -b -1
```

or, more importantly,

```
man journalctl
```

Comment: I won't be able to test it until after work, but I will mark it completed this afternoon! I'm still getting used to this site, thank you for your help.